# Find the largest time interval where the system is guaranteed to have a unique solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the largest interval of uniqueness for the system.
$$
   \vec y'= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & t & t^2 \\
    \frac{t}{t+1} & \frac{1}{t} & \frac{1}{t-5} \\
    sin(t) & cos(t) & tan(\frac{t}{2}) \\
    \end{bmatrix}\vec y + \begin{bmatrix}
    sin(t)  \\
    ln(5t)\\
    t^2  \\
    \end{bmatrix}, \vec y(1)=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2\\ 5\\ \end {bmatrix}
$$
I am struggling to understand differential equations and any advice on the problem would be greatly appreciated. I'm confused as to how to solve the problem with non-constant values in the matrix. Is there a way to answer the question without solving for $\vec y$?

Comment: Thanks! I spotted a typo (the equals sign was a plus sign by mistake). So I have been googling and I think I understand the existence and uniqueness theorem to mean that if the initial value is contained in a continuous interval there is a unique solution on that interval. I also have seen how to do this with one equation, but I think the fact that it is a matrix is confusing me.

Comment: By the general theory of linear systems of ODEs, if $A \colon (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\vec{f} \colon (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are continuous, then the solution of the IVP $\vec{y}'=A(t)\vec{y} + \vec{f}(t)$, $\vec{y}(t_0) = \vec{y}(t_0)$, where $t_0 \in (a, b)$, is defined on the whole of $(a, b)$.  So, in your case we need to find the largest open interval containing $1$ such that both $A(t)$ and $\vec{f}(t)$ are defined for all $t$ in that interval.  And what is the domain of a matrix/vector function?